# Resizing the window and its contents

Tags: python, pyqt5, dynamic-resizing

I started studying PyQt5 and ran into this problem: it is necessary that the image stretches along with the window, and the buttons take the place of the blue rectangles and also change with the size of the window and image.

[image]

Here is my code. I thought about using the resizeEvent function, but so far I don't quite understand how to implement it.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from  PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow  
from K01_C01 import sect01
import sys

class K01(QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self):  
        super(K01, self).__init__() 
        self.w1=QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.w1)

        self.setWindowTitle("ECPT")  
        self.setGeometry(200, 100, 720, 405)

        self.picture = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.picture.setGeometry(0, 0, 750, 400)
        self.picture.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("к01осн.png"))
        self.picture.setScaledContents(True)  
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.setText("C01")
        self.btn.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.btn.setFixedHeight(60)
        self.btn.setFlat(True)
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: yellow; "
                                "font: 28pt Times New Roman }")        
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.C01)

        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn1.setText("C02")
        self.btn1.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.btn1.setFixedHeight(60)
        self.btn1.setFlat(True)
        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: yellow; "
                                "font: 28pt Times New Roman }")  

        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn2.setText("C03")
        self.btn2.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.btn2.setFixedHeight(60)
        self.btn2.setFlat(True)
        self.btn2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: yellow; "
                                "font: 28pt Times New Roman }")  



        self.gird=QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.w1)
        self.gird.addWidget(self.picture, 0,0,6,0)

        self.btngird=QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.btngird.addWidget(self.btn, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gird.addLayout(self.btngird, 2, 0)
        self.btngird.setContentsMargins(-100,-100,-100,-100)

        self.btn1gird=QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.btn1gird.addWidget(self.btn1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gird.addLayout(self.btn1gird, 3, 0)

        self.btn2gird=QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.btn2gird.addWidget(self.btn2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gird.addLayout(self.btn2gird, 4, 0)

    def C01 (self):
        self.wK01=sect01()
        self.wK01.show()



def application():  
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
        window = K01()

        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
        application()
```

Comment: First of all, setting fixed sizes of widgets obviously prevents them to "change with the size of the window and image". Then: 1. why are you overlapping 2 grid two layouts on the same main grid layout?! 2. you're usage of row/column spanning is wrong; 3. even if not impossible, achieving a "perfect" scaling that follows the image is both wrong and pointless: the image doesn't have any relevant content (so you should just have a proper gradient background, and proper spacers/containers/spanning should be eventually used instead), some widgets aren't expected to be resized on certain dimensions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have removed the fixed size of the widgets. Then: 1.I do this so that the layers with the button change inside the layer with the image. 2. Why is it not correct, could you show your version?